# What happens to an equality constraint in the primal when you translate to the dual?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

\begin{align}
\text{maximize}   &\quad   x_1  +3x_2 &     &    \\
\text{subject to} &\quad   x_1  - x_2   =   2 \\                  
& -2x_1 +3x_2  \ge 5 \\
&  \quad\quad\quad x_2  \ge  0
\end{align}

I was able to find the dual LP, but I am not seeing any connections to the original LP. Can I get some pointers?

Find the dual LP.

I first converted the LP to standard form then introduced a new variable.

Let $x_1=r_1-r_2$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}   &\quad   2r_1-2r_2  -5x_2 &     &    \\
\text{subject to} &\quad   r1-r_2+2x_2\geq      1 \\                  
& -r1+r_2-2x_2\geq      -1 \\
&   -r1+r_2-3x_2\geq    3
\end{align}

What happens to an equality constraint in the primal when you translate to the dual?

What happens to a free variable in the primal when you translate to the dual?

Comment: Have your read the table I´ve posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4030208/solving-the-dual-problem-using-the-simplex-method)? I wonder why you cannot answer the questions by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- An equality constraint in the primal corresponds to a free variable in the dual formulation.
- A free variable in the primal corresponds to an equality constraint in the dual formulation.

$$\max x_1+3x_2$$

subject to $$x_1-x_2=2$$
$$-2x_1+3x_5 \ge 5$$
$$x_2 \ge 0$$

We can associate a dual variable $p$ to the first equation and $q$ to the second constraint. $p$ is a free variable.

Since $x_1$ is a free variable in the primal formulation, the corresponding constraint in the dual variable in an equality which is $p-2q=1$.